# unfair linux thread scheduling in single process

Tags: linux, multithreading, kernel, scheduler, perf

I have a process with two threads.

First thread is doing async work - it waits for IO on descriptors and timer events in `epoll_wait`.

Second thread is doing a lot of IO/memory work - it reads data from disk, process it in memory, allocates a lot of new memory, write it to disk and so on.

The problem is that first thread blocks in `epoll_wait` for much longer time, then was requested in timeout for `epoll_wait`(e.g. timeout was specified as 1500 ms and actually return from `epoll_wait` occures in 10 seconds).

This behavior I can reliably reproduce in virtual machine(VirtualBox with Ubuntu 16.04).

Example of behavior from `GDB`:

```
Thread 2.1 "se.real" hit Breakpoint 1, boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::run (this=0x826ebe0, block=true, ops=...) at /opt/com/include/boost/158/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.ipp:392
392 in /opt/com/include/boost/158/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.ipp
16:36:38.986826839
$17 = 1945

Thread 2.1 "se.real" hit Catchpoint 3 (call to syscall epoll_wait), 0xf7fd8be9 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
16:36:38.992081396

<INSIDE KERNEL>


Thread 2.1 "se.real" hit Catchpoint 3 (returned from syscall epoll_wait), 0xf7fd8be9 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
16:36:54.681444938
```

Breakpoint 1 is set to instruction prior to `call epoll_wait`, printed argument is timeout argument value(1945 ms).

Printed time is time from `shell date +"%T.%N"` command.

Catchpoint 3 is syscall catchpoint for `epoll_wait` syscall(first for enter, second for return).

We can easily see that we have spent in kernel for ~ 16 seconds, when 1945 ms were requested.

I have gathered `perf record` with `-e 'sched:*'` events from another reproduction. And I perfectly see:

```
se.real 4277 [001] 113049.144027: sched:sched_switch: prev_comm=se.real prev_pid=4277 prev_prio=120 prev_state=t|K ==> next_comm=strace next_pid=4142 next_prio=120
se.real 4277 [001] 113056.407952: sched:sched_stat_runtime: comm=se.real pid=4277 runtime=153767 [ns] vruntime=409222246640 [ns]
```

No any other sched event for thread 4277(first thread with async IO and `epoll_wait`) for ~7 seconds. In mean time there are a lot of sched activity between this events. This activity includes both second thread(thread with a lot of IO/memory work), `swapper`/`kswapd`, and other userspace processes.

The question is what I can do to give a chance for running first thread?

**Update:** changing scheduling policy to `SCHED_FIFO` for process doesn't solve problem - I'm still able stably reproduce the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you're logging the timeout correctly and you're not mucking with thread priorities?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I have a virtualbox image on a specific hardware server where I observe this behavior stably. I see same timeout values from other sources - e.g. strace, perf trace, etc. And I have recorded values on which timeout value is calculated and manually checked that everything is right.

Comment: Could it be a testing/profiling artifact?  Maybe `epoll_wait()` does return in the time expected, but GDB and `perf` don't see the event until some time later?  Does the problem appear when you're not running under GDB and don't have `perf` running?  If you take a millisecond (or higher) precision timestamp right before calling `epoll_wait()` and one right after it returns, how much time actually elapses?

Comment: Through perf I record scheduler events. And I see that scheduler didn't run first thread while thread was blocked in epoll_wait inside kernel. As far as I understand it means that thread simply didn't get a chance to return from epoll_wait.
I see this behavior under ptrace(GDB, strace), while using perf utility without ptrace and without profiling at all.
And before blaming scheduler I spent days in my code understanding where I'm blocked. I have a perf report I can share.